# how to transfer parameters after redirect to index.html？

Tags: objective-c, gcdwebserver

```
GCDWebServer *_webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
[_webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
                           path:@"/"
                   requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class] 
     processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse(GCDWebServerRequest request){
                       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"index.html" relativeToURL:request.URL];
                       return [GCDWebServerResponse responseWithRedirect:url permanent:NO]; 
                   }];
```

I tried a lot of methods, but I couldn't pass the parameters。

after redirect to index.html, how to transfer parameters to index.html???

Comment: what type is _webserver? And did you check your typo? looks a bit weirdo

Comment: _webserver = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];